Motion blur rendering not capturing time-dependent shader changes
I'm encountering an issue with motion blur rendering in Blender where time-dependent shader changes are not being captured. Here are the details:
Setup:
I'm using Blender to render an image with motion blur. The scene contains a moving cube.
Shutter time for motion blur is set to 200.

The cube has a shader with a 4D noise texture. The W input of the noise texture is connected to the #frame value to create time-dependent changes.

Expected Behavior:
The rendered image should show the motion-blurred path of the cube.
The volumetric texture of the cube should change along its path, reflecting the time-dependent shader.
Actual Behavior:
The motion-blurred path of the cube is visible in the render.
However, the volumetric texture appears static and doesn't show any changes along the path.
Rendered image using cycles:

When manually scrubbing through frames in the timeline, I can see the texture changing in every frame.


Rendering individual frames without motion blur shows the texture changing as expected.
How can I make blender to capture the changes in the shader in the rendering?

Apparently this is something that is not implemented in blender (yet).
I also tried using shutter speed of 1, and different setups, but nothing seems to be working.
I am not going to close the question in case someone has some workaround.
I also tried using the composition and vector speed, but it has the same problems...
